# Циклический сдвиг элементов вниз в односвязном линейном списке

Tags: c++

Необходимо в односвязном линейном списке сдвинуть циклически вниз элементы.
Язык с++
Структура:

```
struct LIST {
string stroka;
LIST* next;
```

};

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Вниз - это к началу или к концу? :) В любом случае запоминайте указатель на предшествующий элемент и корректно меняйте связи...

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://studassistent.ru/c/vypolnit-ciklicheskiy-sdvig-spiska-na-n-elementov-vpravo-ili-vlevo-c-si) представлено решение вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Вниз - это к началу или к концу? :) В любом случае запоминайте указатель на предшествующий элемент и корректно меняйте связи...

https://studassistent.ru/c/vypolnit-ciklicheskiy-sdvig-spiska-na-n-elementov-vpravo-ili-vlevo-c-si